# Oracle SQL-count number of null by group and add a new column

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to count number of open cases grouped by ID (by counting number of "null" in the CloseDate column), and add a new column into the table. I am not sure how to do that. Any thoughts will be appreciated, thank you!

[image: ID Service Status CloseDate 1 A Closed 7/1/2020 1 A Open 1 A Open 2 A Open 3 A Closed 7/2/2020]

The idea result would be:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses a SUM window function (don't use COUNT() with a CASE statement like this because the 0's would get included as part of the "count", which isn't what you want).

This also avoids using a subquery, so it'll perform faster than any query that does (especially if you're dealing with large table) because it doesn't need to reread data from the same table. One of the main advantages to using window functions is that they prevent the need to reread table data, so don't force your query to reread from the table by putting the window function in a separate subquery if you can avoid it.

Assuming your table's name is t

```
select
       ClientID,
       Service,
       Status,
       CloseDate,
       sum(
         case 
           when CloseDate is null 
             then 1 
            else 0 
           end
        ) over(
            partition by ClientID
        ) as OpenCount
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the below query with having window function -

```
SELECT ClientID,
       Service,
       Status,
       CloseDate,
       OpenCount,
       SUM(CASE WHEN CloseDate IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID)
  FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Comment: I think you want `ELSE NULL` rather than `ELSE 0`.  Also, I would simply use `WHEN CloseDate IS NULL` rather than the NVL condition.

Comment: This would give you a count of 3 for clientId 1, and a count of 1 for clientId 3 because the 0's will be included in the count. I wouldn't use the NVL either, and this forces the database to have to convert the date to a varchar2 (assuming the CloseDate is actually a DATE column) Could just do CASE WHEN CloseDate IS NULL....

Comment: @PhilGoldenberg, Corrected the query.

Answer (score 0):

With a subquery inside the select clause, you can reach the desired output.

**In sql**

```
SELECT ClientID,
       Service,
       Status,
       CloseDate,
       ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY ClientID) FROM t1 WHERE t1.ClientID = t.ClientID AND t1.CloseDate IS NULL),0) AS OpenCount
FROM t1 t;
```

**In oracle**

```
SELECT ClientID,
       Service,
       Status,
       CloseDate,
       coalesce((SELECT COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY clientid ORDER BY clientid) FROM t1 WHERE t1.ClientID = t.ClientID AND t1.CloseDate IS NULL FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY),0) AS OpenCount
FROM t1 t;
```

- sql demo [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7b3db870b27176c426be7145c2d95caf)
- oracle demo [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1a3bfc63b0ab2914442a638282719038)

Answer (score 0):

You could count the number of times that the `closedate` is null:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when closedate is null then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by clientid)
from t;
```

Or you could count the number of opens and subtract the number of closes:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case status when 'open' then 1 when 'closed' then -1) over (partition by clientid)
from t;
```

These are equivalent for the data you provided.  I'm not sure if one is really better for your problem than the other.